# python - how to pipe the output using popen?

Tags: python, popen

I want to `pipe` output of my file using `popen`, how can I do that?

**test.py**:

```
while True:
  print"hello"
```

**a.py**  :

```
import os  
os.popen('python test.py')
```

I want to pipe the output using `os.popen`.
how can i do the same?

Answer (score 17):

First of all, os.popen() is deprecated, use the subprocess module instead.

You can use it like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

output = Popen(['command-to-run', 'some-argument'], stdout=PIPE)
print output.stdout.read()
```

Comment: The example shows this. You should use: Popen(['python', 'test.py'], stdout=PIPE)

Comment: Per the subprocess documentaion [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), and the other answer, proc.communicate()[0] should be used instead of stdout.read() to avoid deadlocking

Answer (score 12):

Use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, here is an example:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(["python","test.py"], stdout=PIPE)
output = proc.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: it will hang until MemoryError happens. If the output is unlimited (as in the `test.py` case) then `.communicate()` shouldn't be used. Read incrementally using `proc.stdout` directly instead, see [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Answer (score 4):

This will print just the first line of output:

a.py:

```
import os
pipe = os.popen('python test.py')
a = pipe.readline()
print a
```

...and this will print all of them

```
import os
pipe = os.popen('python test.py')
while True:
    a = pipe.readline()
    print a
```

(I changed test.py to this, to make it easier to see what's going on:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
x = 0
while True:
    x = x + 1
    print "hello",x
```

)